# How to Delay between subsequent append html to a div using Jquery or javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, settimeout

In My application I am facing some problem with setting delay when appending some html to a div within a array. (subsequent time). Please see the following code. 10 times I am appending " Hello World" text into a div. I want some delay after each append.

```
function someFunction(){
    for(var i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
         addElement();
    }
}

function addElement()
{
     $('.SomeDiv').append('<div>Hello World</div>');
}
```

I have tried like this:

```
 function someFunction(){
    for(var i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        setTimeOut(function(){
            addElement();
        },1000);             
    }
}
```

But this is not working. How can I do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
function someFunction() {
    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        setTimeout(function(){
            addElement();
        }, 1000 * i);
    }
}

function addElement() {
    $('.SomeDiv').append('<div>Hello World</div>');
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/C4hwg/

Note `1000 * i` increasing timeout, it does the trick.

Comment: Thanks @dfsq.. It works. Can you please tell me what's the differences here?? OR any reference where I can see the documentation to see this kind of tricks. I think this could be some tricks to work setTimeout with loop.

Answer (score 2):

`setInterval` or `setTimeout` are the better way to do this, but you can also use jQuery `delay()`:

```
for(var i=0;i<10;i++)
{
    $('.SomeDiv').delay(i * 1000).queue(function (next) {
        $(this).append('<div>Hello World</div>');
        next();
    });
}
```

### [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/R69U9/1/)

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to use `setInterval`' not `setTimeout`. `setInterval` will execute a function, wait N milliseconds, then execute it again. `setTimeout` just delays N milliseconds, then executes once.

```
var count = 0;

var interval = setInterval(function () {
    addElement();
    count++;
    if (count >= 10) {
        clearInterval(interval);
    }
}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try using setInterval...

```
var count = 0;
var placeHolder = setInterval(function() {
    addElement();
    count = count + 1; //i forget if ++ works...
    if(count > 9)
        clearInterval(placeHolder);

}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 1):

Some upgrade to your function:

```
function someFunction(){
    for(var i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        setTimeout(function(){
            addElement();
        }, i*1000 );             
    }
}
```

Remember , when creating many `setTimeout`s it affects performance.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/CSPbb/

Comment: Thanks @Cherniv.. It works. Can you please tell me what's the differences here?? OR any reference where I can see the documentation to see this kind of tricks. I think this could be some tricks to work setTimeout with loop.

Comment: just want to point out that this adds 10 setTimeout handles (however you would describe that), whereas you really only need 1 setInterval handle to do the same thing.  Personally, I think setInterval makes more sense.

Comment: @HannanHossain `setTimeout` is kind of asynchronous function calls , you tell it what function you want to run and what time you want to wait before. So in your case we're creating 10 "waiters" , when first will run in 0 milliseconds (1000*0) , second in 1000 milliseconds (1000*1) , third in 2000 milliseconds and so on..

Comment: This is going to create a debugging nightmare for whatever poor programmer falls upon this code in the future.